# How to check if difference between two dates with timespan is exactly 1 year using c# linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am fetching a list of data and using linq I am converting it to my desired model.

Below is my sample code:

```
    public JsonResult GetDataList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
        List<Model> ModelList = new List<Model>();
        try
        {
            Services.ServiceClient ServiceClient = new Services.ServiceClient();
            ModelList = ServiceClient.GetAllData().Select(x => new Model
            {
                ID = x.ID,
                Name = x.Name,
                Description = x.Description,
                Category = x.Category,
                DtActive = x.DtActive,
                DtExpire = x.DtExpire,                
                IsLive = ((x.DtActive.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date) && (x.DtExpire == (x.DtActive.Value.AddYears(1)))) ? true : false
            }).ToList();

            if (ServiceClient.ResponseStatus == RestClientHelper.ResponseCode.FAILUER)
            {
                errorMessages.Add(ServiceClient.ResponseMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessages.Add(ex.Message);
        }

        if (errorMessages.Count == 0)
        {
            return Json(ModelList.AsEnumerable().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Data = ModelList.AsEnumerable().ToDataSourceResult(request), Errors = errorMessages });
        }
    }
```

So everything is coming fine but when I am trying to set "IsLive" field depending on condition it is always coming false.

I want it to set to "true" only if "DtActive" is less than today's date and "DtExpiry" is exactly 1 year greater than "DtActive".

Can anyone please help me. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean "DtExpiry" is exactly 1 year greater than "DtActive" or do you actually want "DtExpiry" *at most* 1 year greater than "DtActive"?

Comment: exactly 1 year actually I am setting it exactly 1 year greater than DtActive while saving data through ajax call. Thhis is the condition in my application.

Comment: What if dates are `29 Feb 2016` and `28 Feb 2017` / `01 Mar 2017`?

Comment: "Exactly" including seconds, milliseconds, etc.?

Comment: So what are the values here? Are they actually dates and times, or just dates? (I would strongly advise you to reconsider using DateTime.Now unless you genuinely want it to be using the system time zone, as a side note.)

Comment: To the down voter:  you should explain yourself.  This seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: `x.DtActive.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date` could probably be rewritten as `x.DtActive.Value.Date < DateTime.Today`.

Comment: Actually in my application when I say "GoLive" to a component it sets the Active date and expiry date exactly 1 year greater than Active date. So in grid I want to show user that these components are live...and as I can't add any other field in db for this I'll have to recognize this way only

Comment: Added hour/min/seconds agnostic answer, if is not what you need (not sure what you need), add a comment and will remove it :-)

Comment: Why rely on the 1 year timespan and not just say that it is currently live when the current date is between the activation date and the expiry date?

Comment: @grek40 that's correct point. But I am doing it according to my client specification.

Comment: sometimes clients need to be protected... from themself

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 I mostly agree, but I tend to remove the "sometimes" from this statement.

Comment: Understood grek40 and DarkSquirrel42. Will try to set it this way. Thanks for the suggestions everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

To test this I made 2 dates, yesterday and yesterday a year ago. Then comparing them like this worked perfectly:

```
DateTime dtActive = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 );//Yesterday
DateTime dtExp = DateTime.Now.AddYears( 1 ).AddDays( -1 );//Last year yesterday

if ( dtActive.Date < DateTime.Now.Date && dtExp.AddYears( -1 ).Date == dtActive.Date )
{
    //Success
}
```

Comment: Seeing `x ? true : false` in a question is one thing, but taking it into the answer is a different beast. Please just use `x` in such a case and don't promote unnecessary ternary operator usage.

Comment: @grek40 Its not unnecessary as he uses it in a select statement so it will not function as if

Comment: I never talked about `if`, i'm just saying that a ternary operator that ends in `true : false` is always unnecessary (in C#): `true ? true : false == true` and `false ? true : false == false` and `x ? true : false == x`. So just write `IsLive = (dtActive.Date < DateTime.Now.Date && dtExp.AddYears(-1).Date == dtActive.Date)` without ternary operator and without `if`.

Comment: @grek40 Ah like that, yeah thats true didn't think of that. I just copied the statement from the question and changed just the conditions to be correct